# Positron and other particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

> Positron is a particle which has the same mass as an electron . But it has positive charge on it . When electron and positron combine, they annihilate each other with the release of energy in the form of two very high energy photons.
>
> if the energy released on annihilation of an electron and a positron is 0.5 Mev(Million electron volts),find the frequency of the wave which is carrying this photon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** :-  Use **Plank's Relation**,
$$E=h \nu\ $$
where $h$ is the plank's constant = $6.626 \times\ 10^{-34}$ and proceed...